# Make zen coding support less file in sublime text2

Tags: sublimetext, emmet

How can I make zen coding support less file in sublime text2?

Comment: Do you have the Zen Coding plugin installed? If so, a simple `tab` would do the trick.

Comment: yes, I stalled zen coding. and I can expand html exceptions use "tab"; but no effection for css exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install latest version of ST 2 (right now, -build 2165), and using package control (version 1.4.1), install the zen coding plugin (rather package). Then the expansion engine works fine.

I am windows user, and it was not working until last version (-build 2139), though MAC users were approving its execution.

Links:

[Package control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control)

*Awesome Software and both plugins too.*

Edit:

Sorry, the answer is not relative, but still let it be here as it is the best alternative till date.

To see what is your expansion key, go to :

> $PACKAGES_PATH/ZenCoding/zen-settings.sublime-settings for keys and their default values.

Please give an example how you want to employ LESS using ZC,

like for html, we use:

```
.container>(.content>.article>.p>lorem)+(aside>h1{Side Bar}+ul>li*4>a{home,about,contact,blog})
```

My personal opinion will be using ST 2's snippet-expansion.

Never mind, To learn more about how to adapt for LESS, Try this source instead:

[Zen Coding Discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/zen-coding).

Learn Zen-Coding from its developer ;-P .

Comment: or try the new and improved version of zen coding: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime
works much better